# How can I test if a java.lang.Math method has been called?

Tags: java, math, junit, mocking, jmockit

I'm attempting to write code that checks whether an implementation of code depends on `Math.sqrt()` in Java.

I've tried using the code below with JUnit and jMockit which throws an error:

```
@Test 
public void testSquareNumsWithoutSQRT(@Mocked final Math m) {
  // ...
}
```

After doing some research I now understand why I can't mock that library, but that still leaves me with the original problem. Is there a way to check if a method is making a call to the Math library?

Comment: I assume reading the code is not an option.

Comment: No.  _Why do you care?_  (You shouldn't.)

Comment: It simply is my requirement and I need to comply with it. I have found that parsing the file and looking for the call takes care of my issue though and unfortunately I can't share the rest of the code.

Comment: @RodCardenas just because there is an invocation of `Math.square` in your code doesn't mean your code is actually passing the correct parameters nor is it actually using the result of that invocation. So parsing the file also has its flaws.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage) to mock final classes and static methods. But if you have to use PowerMock it means there's something wrong with your code.

And remember, to avoid fragile tests, **you shouldn't test implementation but results**.

There're a lot of useful articles about mocks. See [this one](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/10/WhenToMock.html) for example. This is an excerpt from it:

> The mocking structure become tightly coupled to implementation details causing many tests to break when those details are modified.

Is that really important for you to know the way square root is computed or you rather need to know if a result is correct?

Comment: Jakub, the way the task was given, the requirement focuses on checking for the implementation details first and the correctness of the output second. In this case it was important to us that the code did not make use of the Math.sqrt method.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question seems unorthodox, but the requirements of my task were to verify some implemented methods did not use specific java.lang.Math methods.

To solve it without affecting the system, I resorted to parsing the code and searching for the code that was not supposed to be there.